# NSTokenField with mixed token/string input, possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

When entering an invalid email in Mail's **NSTokenField** one get's this (a **mix of token** and **plain string values**):

[image]

Is there any recommendable way to accomplish this?
Is NSTokenField even the right tool for this? Or would I be abusing it?

In this particular project I need to allow the user to enter a file name pattern
*(there are several other use cases though)*, with support for predefined tokens.

Right now I'm requiring the input to be entered like this:

```
Glue Text %[Tag]Other Glue Text%[Another Tag]More Text
```

I'd like to change this to some fool-proof graphical solution like this:
[image]

NSTokenField always(!) turns entered text into tokens.

Either I'm using the wrong keywords in my web searches,
or I'm really the first to need this (mixed) behaviour?!

I did read thru Apple's NSTokenField Guide, but couldn't find any info on my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate method `tokenField:styleForRepresentedObject:` to return either `NSRoundedTokenStyle` for tokens or `NSPlainTextTokenStyle` for other text. The represented object for an token is the token string itself, unless your delegate returns other objects.

This should do the trick for your case:

```
- (NSTokenStyle)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
 styleForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    if ([representedObject rangeOfString: @"%["].location == 0) {
        return NSRoundedTokenStyle;
    } else {
        return NSPlainTextTokenStyle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you first have to define a tokenizing character, which in your case would be %

```
[tokenField setTokenizingCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"%%"]];
```

The input string needs to changed as well into:

> Glue Text %[Tag]%Other Glue
>   Text%[Another Tag]%More Text

... so that Cocoa knows where the token ends.

And if you want [Tag] to be displayed as Tag in the token field, you also need to implement the `tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:` method:

```
- (NSTokenStyle)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
 displayStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    if ([representedObject rangeOfString: @"["].location == 0) {
        return [(NSString*)representedObject substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [(NSString*)representedObject length]-2)];

    return representedObject;
}
```

However, this has a big drawback : if you copy or just move a token, Cocoa will call `tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:` and the copied/moved token will be changed to regular text Tag instead of the token [Tag].

If someone has a solution to the above problem, I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: You need to implement the delegate method - (BOOL)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField writeRepresentedObjects:(NSArray *)objects toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard