# How to do a mixed input NSTokenField

Tags: nstokenfield

I'm trying to get an `NSTokenField` working that allows editing [to a similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244909/nstokenfield-with-mixed-token-string-input-possible).

The answer that was provided gave me the key but something is still off.  What should the token character set be set as?  My tags will be in this format "< token text >".  Setting the character tokenizer to " " results in the " " between words being removed.

What should I be using as the token character set?  This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I would use " " as the tokenizer and then add a space at the end of your display string which is not in your editing string.

So -tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject: would return "Hello " and -tokenField:editingStringForRepresentedObject: would return "Hello".

The alternative would be using "<" and ">" as the tokenizing characters, but I could see a lot of potential issues arising from that.

Comment: It appears that may work, I was able to solve my issue by using "" as the tokenizer and responding to key events and handling them according and modifying the objectValue.

Comment: That actually works very well, but the problem is it doubles the " " character in between tokens.  Weird behavior.