# NSTokenField for WinForms

Tags: winforms, nstokenfield

Is there an available `NSTokenField` replacement from Mac OS X that I can use with WinForms? I would like to be able to add them by just manipulating the string with my tokens like this:  "$MyToken$" and be replaced with "My Token" (I would have a data structure with this information) with the highlighted token. Like this: [NSTokenField with mixed token/string input, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244909/nstokenfield-with-mixed-token-string-input-possible)

Also, I would like it to have have a little `X` button to remove the token.

[image]

Thanks!

*edit*: I do have a preference for commercially avaiable or FOSS, only with certain licenses (Apache, MS-PL).