# iOS Token Field

Tags: ios, user-interface

Any way of doing the described in this question in iOS?

[NSTokenField with mixed token/string input, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244909/nstokenfield-with-mixed-token-string-input-possible)

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know there are no equivalent Classes for iOS, anyway there are a couple of project around that do this pretty well, for example [TITokenField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/titokenfield). You can use the control as it is or grab just the logic behind.