# Mixing tokens and strings in NSTokenField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstokenfield

I want to have an `NSTokenField` that contains both plain text and tokens.  That's the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244909/nstokenfield-with-mixed-token-string-input-possible), but the answers there haven't solved it for me.  Maybe I'm missing something, or maybe Apple changed something in the 5 years since those answers were posted.

Specifically, let's say I want to type "hello%tok%" and have it turn into this:

[image: image of text "hello" and token "TOKEN"]

In order to try to remove chances for confusion, I always use a custom represented object, of one of the following classes, rather than a plain string...

```
@interface Token : NSObject
@end

@implementation Token
@end


@interface WrappedString : NSObject
@property (retain) NSString* text;
@end

@implementation WrappedString
@end
```

Here are my delegate methods:

```
- (NSString *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
    displayStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    NSString * displayString = nil;
    if ([representedObject isKindOfClass: [WrappedString class]])
    {
        displayString = ((WrappedString*)representedObject).text;
    }
    else
    {
        displayString = @"TOKEN";
    }
    return displayString;
}

- (NSTokenStyle)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
                styleForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    NSTokenStyle theStyle = NSPlainTextTokenStyle;
    if ([representedObject isKindOfClass: [Token class]])
    {
        theStyle = NSRoundedTokenStyle;
    }

    return theStyle;
}

- (NSString *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
        editingStringForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject
{
    NSString * editingString = representedObject;
    if ([representedObject isKindOfClass: [Token class]])
    {
        editingString = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        editingString = ((WrappedString*)representedObject).text;
    }
    return editingString;
}

- (id)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField
    representedObjectForEditingString:(NSString *)editingString
{
    id repOb = nil;
    if ([editingString isEqualToString:@"tok"])
    {
        repOb = [[[Token alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    else
    {
        WrappedString* wrapped = [[[WrappedString alloc]
            init] autorelease];
        wrapped.text = editingString;
        repOb = wrapped;
    }
    return repOb;
}
```

As I'm typing the "hello", none of the delegate methods is called, which seems reasonable.  When I type the first "%", there are 3 delegate calls:

1. `tokenField:representedObjectForEditingString:` gets the string "hello" and turns it into a `WrappedString` representation.
2. `tokenField:styleForRepresentedObject:` gets that `WrappedString` and returns `NSPlainTextTokenStyle`.
3. `tokenField:editingStringForRepresentedObject:` gets the `WrappedString` and returns "hello".

The first two calls seem reasonable.  I'm not sure about number 3, because the token should be editable but it's not being edited yet.  I would have thought that `tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:` would get called, but it doesn't.

When I type "tok", no delegate methods are called.  When I type the second "%", `tokenField:representedObjectForEditingString:` receives the string "hellotok", where I would have expected to see just "tok".  So I never get a chance to create the rounded token.

If I type the text in the other order, "%tok%hello", then I do get the expected result, a round token followed by plain "hello".

By the way, the [Token Field Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/TokenFieldPurpose/TokenFieldPurpose.html) says

> Note that there can be only one token per token field that is configured for the plain-text token style.

which seems to imply that it's not possible to freely mix plain text and tokens.

Comment: I think Apple changed something and NSPlainTextTokenStyle isn't working anymore. I don't know if it is a bug or a feature. Old (2015) sample code uses NSPlainTextTokenStyle but it has the same problem and I can't download the sample anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked myself whether I had seen mixed text and tokens anywhere in standard apps, and I had.  In the **Language & Text** panel of **System Preferences**, under the **Formats** tab, clicking one of the "Customize..." buttons brings up a dialog containing token fields.  Here's part of one.

[image]

Here, you don't create tokens by typing a tokenizing character, you drag and drop prototype tokens.

To make one of the prototype tokens, make another `NSTokenField` and set it to have no background or border and be selectable but not editable.  When your window has loaded, you can initialize the prototype field using the `objectValue` property, e.g.,

```
self.protoToken.objectValue = @[[[[Token alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

You need to set up a delegate for each prototype token field as well as your editable token field.  In order to be able to drag and drop tokens, your delegate must implement `tokenField:writeRepresentedObjects:toPasteboard:` and `tokenField:readFromPasteboard:`.

Comment: Looks promising for my use case... hopefully the other text will be editable "normally" but we'll see. `autorelease` in the house!